# Why isn't my chain following the bezier circle?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a necklace. I did find some similar questions and attempted to copy the answers (e.g. put object origins at the same point in space, mess with array/curve axis settings, Edit mode -> <kbd>N</kbd> -> Transform -> Mean Radius = 1), but I can't seem to identify what's going on here... Unless maybe I used the wrong curve type, but the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWfM6KDHCo0) I followed also used this circle. Help me out, please? Thanks!

(Also, a curious question: Is it done or would it be better to model half the necklace chain and add a mirror modifier?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I use comments to ask a related but not-main question? Is it better to make a necklace by mirroring half a curve instead?

Comment: Noted; I added a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your curve was rotated on the X axis, which makes the chain go crazy, so first apply the rotation (<kbd>CtrlA</kbd>):

[image]

then choose the right *Deform Axis* in the *Curve* modifier (-Y):

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was simple XD; I didn't realize the significance of applying (Ctrl+A for latecomers) scale, rotation, etc. until now. (Rotation was the thing I needed to apply, though it is kinda obvious from the image.) Thank you!

Comment: yes because if the curve is rotated it makes the chain transformation go crazy, you can test it: once you've fixed the problem, select the curve and rotate it